# multiplication of arrays in python

Tags: python, image-processing, face-recognition

Here is the line of code that makes the problem in python. I'm working with images and there is no categorical data.

```
normalized_face_vector = [88, 90000]
eigen_vectors = [88, 88]
low_dimension_to_high_dimension = normalized_face_vector.dot(eigen_vectors)
```

when the above line execute it gives below error.

```
shapes (88,90000) and (88,88) not aligned: 90000 (dim 1) != 88 (dim 0)
```

**How can I perform multiplication of normalized_face_vector with eigen_vectors?**

Comment: Transpose the matrix, or reverse the operands. However, the operation works equally well with the eigenvector matrix as it is or transposed, but you’d get different results. So if you don’t know what you’re doing here, you need to stop and find out first. Don’t just force the operands to match and expect to get correct results, because they can match in different ways and only one way is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting 'ValueError: shapes not aligned' on SciKit Linear Regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271725/getting-valueerror-shapes-not-aligned-on-scikit-linear-regression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error because dimensions of your both matrix are not proper.
In your error message it is clearly mentioned that : *shapes (88,90000) and (88,88) not aligned: **90000 (dim 1) != 88 (dim 0)** .*

**For Dot product No. of columns of Matrix_A must be Equal to No. of Rows of Matrix_B.**

In your case you can take **transpose** of matrix_A and then apply dot product.

Check out this example this may help you :

```
import numpy as np
Matrix_A=[               #4x5
    [3,4,6,4,6],
    [3,8,7,6,6],
    [2,7,9,2,2],
    [7,1,2,7,4]]
Matrix_B=[               #4x4
    [8,4,9,5],
    [3,2,7,3],
    [9,7,2,6],
    [3,2,3,7]]
Matrix_A=np.array(a)
Matrix_B=np.array(b)
Matrix_C=np.dot(Matrix_A.transpose(),Matrix_B)
Matrix_C
```